# "Windows failed to start" loop with 0xc0000225. No install discs, EasyRE/USB iso hasn't worked

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, iso-image

I've been suffering from this "Windows failed to start" loop with 0xc0000225 for 3 days now and I still can't fix it. The major problem is that I don't have any sort of installation disc.

However, I have tried EasyRE via both CD and USB but both result in the same problem.  I try to perform an 'Automated Repair' on my computer and I get in red text "The selected partition is corrupted and could not be accessed or repaired. Please select a different drive to continue." It is also labeled as NO under Active.

Since I do not have a the installation discs, I made a USB with a Windows_7_Recovery_Disc  iso (as shown here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/31541-windows-7-usb-dvd-download-tool.html) but it also doesn't work. I get a blue screen that says "RECOVERY You pc needs to be repaired. The application or operating system could not be uploaded because a required file is missing or contains errors...

File:\WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc0000225

You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation media, contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer."

Thanks in advance!
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

### To start...

For this you will need some form of recovery media, which means you'll need to use another Windows 7 PC to create it. Follow the [instructions at SevenForums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2083-system-repair-disc-create.html) to do that.

## The repair

Rebuild the BCD. Boot into the recovery media, and select Command Prompt. Type

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

and hit enter.

### Reboot

If the above didn't fix the error, you may have to set your Windows partition to Active. Reboot back into the recovery media, and from the command line, type

```
diskpart
select disk 1
list part
```

You'll then have to determine which partition should be your active partition, and then set it to active:

```
select partition x
active
quit
```

Replace X with the correct partition number.

### Reboot

If that still hasn't fixed the issue, you'll have to restore the MBR. This is a bit more complex.

Reboot back into the recovery disk, and select command prompt.

Now we're going to have to determine the drive letter your recovery disk is on:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
list volume
```

Search for the item that has CD-ROM in the Type column and make note of the value in the LTR column - this is the drive letter.

```
exit
```

Simply type the drive letter like so, and hit enter:

```
D:
```

Then type:

```
cd boot
dir
```

You should see a bootsect.exe file listed. If you don't: **STOP**, go and get a Windows Installation Disk and try again. Otherwise...

Type

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr
```

and hit Enter.

Once you see **Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes**, type `exit` and then reboot your computer.

Hopefully then your issue will be fixed.

Please note you follow these instructions at your own risk, and I assume you have a basic knowledge of Command Prompt. If you're unsure, please ask a professional.

Comment: I followed the instructions to create a system repair disc using my laptop (same Windows edition and 64-bit) but the result is similar to all the times I have created an install/repair disc via USB or ISO--- nothing. This time I'm simply led back to the WINDOWS FAILED TO START PROBLEM. Thus, I can't even start your repair instructions. Btw I can't access the Advanced Startup Options at all (hitting F8 does nothing)

Comment: Make sure your BIOS boot order is set to allow either your CD drive or USB drive to boot before your hard drive.